# npm install from google git repo

Tags: git, npm

Trying to get started with google hosted git repos.  I'm able to push my repos to google just fine.  The issue now though is, how can I `npm install` these private git repos?

I tried

```
npm i git+ssh://source.developers.google.com/p/myprojectID/r/myrepo.git
```

but I get this error

> ENOENT: no such file or directory

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try to use it: `npm i https://source.developers.google.com/p/myprojectID/r/myrepo.git https`

Comment: Get the same error still